# Passing the Dataflow Parameter to Sink Key column in Azure Data factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I wanted to implement SCD type 2 logic but using dynamic tables and dynamic key fields from Config Table, I have a challenge to pass the Data Flow Parameter as Sink Key Column for my Alter Row activity, it is not taking the parameter values and always gives the error as invalid key column name, I tried picking the Dataflow parameter for the expression builder at sink key column and trying to pass the value from alter row transformation and I have named the field with parameter in the select statement as well , any help or suggestion highly appreciated

Please clink below image
[Sample How I wanted to Pass Dynamic Values in Sink Mapping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yaGUQ.png) 
[Trying to Give the Dynamic Value to Key Value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6XwX1.png)

Comment: On the Sink Key Columns property, did you click on "Custom expression" so that you can enter parameters and expressions?

Comment: yes I added parameter but i get the error as at sink side mapping it is working only if I have the fixed name instead of using $name I wanted to pass the dynamic name even at sink side mapping

Comment: Are you able to share the data flow script? Can you go to the Script button on top right of the data flow designer and paste the script here?

Comment: Hi Mark appreciate for trying to help, I have added images how I wanted to pass the dynamic values for sink ( for Sink transformation:  key field name should be dynamic  and also for input and output port  need to be dynamic so that name is decided at runtime  , as i am using it for multiple tables reading from Config Table) thanks a ton in advance  , so kindly let me know how can I achieve it with Sink , ( in the above example it is not allowing me please see the images attached )

Answer (score 0):

You have "List of columns" selected, so ADF is looking for a column in your target table that is literally called "$TargetPK1Parameter".

Change the selector to "Custom expression" and enter a string array parameter. The parameter can be an array of strings that represent names of key columns in your target table.

It should look something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks Iain I will try it as I could not able to do earlier we used TSQL

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar problem when trying to pass a composite key, parameterized, as part of the update method to sink.  This now allows me to fully parameterise my dataflow and it handles both composite keys and single columns keys.

Here's how the data looks in my config table:

UpsertKeyColumn = `DOMNAME,DDLANGUAGE,AS4LOCAL,VALPOS,AS4VERS`

[image: Column value]

A parameter value is set in the dataflow

Upsert_Key_Column = `@item().UpsertKeyColumn`

[image: Set parameter]

Finally, in the Sink settings, Custom Expression is selected for Key columns and the following expression is entered - `split($upsert_key_column,',')`

[image: Custom Expression]

Comment: Thanks IainAskham for the reply, definitely I will try it , as we were passing the deadline we used TSQL

Comment: I tried above solution but its giving error as :
  Error: {"StatusCode":"DFExecutorUserError","Message":"Job failed due to reason: at Sink 'sink1': SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 310\ninvalid identifier 'BI_TEST.\"ID,DATALAKEMODIFIED_DATETIME\"'" 
key column : split($KeyCol, ',')
KeyCol : "'ID,DATALAKEMODIFIED_DATETIME'"
any idea on this one?