# Key columns field in Sink in Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

When building a data flow and then sinking it into exsiting SQL database, the 'Key column' field in the 'Settinds' tab causes a problem, because it seems that it cannot take the existing parameter.
A similar question was recently asked: [Passing the Dataflow Parameter to Sink Key column in Azure Data factory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67163563/passing-the-dataflow-parameter-to-sink-key-column-in-azure-data-factory/67202095#67202095), but even if I choose a 'Custom expression' and then take my existing paramter -  a composite key 'Column1,Column2,Column3' that I used before for hashing - the rectangular remains red, i.e. it does not accept the expression. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

[Visual expression builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jMWLz.png)
[Then](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7OFr.png)